# Refer to different id's within the same query in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to brind a lot of columns from several tables using LEFT JOIN. My starting point is the orders table and I bring the vendor name from the "Address_table". Then I add another table with order details and then the shipping information of each order detail.

My problem is that I need to bring a different record from "Address_table" to refer onether id's detailed in shipment table as of "origin_id" and "destination_id".

In other words, "address_id", "origin_id" and "destination_id" are all records from "Address_table". I brought the first one related to the vendor, how can I retrieve the other two?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vUSF.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not exactly clear in terms of the tables and their relationships. It is, however, clear what the problem is. You need to join against the same table twice using different columns.

In order to do that you need to use *table aliases*. For example, you can do:

```
select *
from shipment s
left join address_table a on a.address_id = s.origin_id
left join address_table b on b.address_id = s.destination_id
```

In this example the table `address_table` is joined twice against the table `shipment`; the first time we use `a` as an alias, the second time `b`. This way you can differentiate how to pick the right columns and make the joins work as you need them to.